# SQL query to find duplicate rows, in any table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm looking for a schema-independent query.  That is, if I have a `users` table or a `purchases` table, the query should be equally capable of catching duplicate rows in either table without any modification (other than the `from` clause, of course).

I'm using T-SQL, but I'm guessing there should be a general solution.

Comment: TSQL as in Sybase or SQL Server?  What version, too

Comment: A generic process would need to be able to identify and ignore the primary key column(s) when looking for duplicates?

Comment: You call something a duplicate when one/more fields have same values for multiple rows. You have to define some parameter fixed liek similar column names etc.

Comment: catching duplicate rows? And do what with them? Exclude them from the results, only include them in the results? Delete them from the tables? Also what exactly do you mean by schema-independent?

Comment: It's a duplicate when all of the fields of two or more rows have the same values--there is no primary key, and I won't be adding one (I can go into more detail on this if you're curious, but it's irrelevant to the solution).  Also, it's SQL Server 2005.  @Conrad: detecting them is enough, and schema-independent means I don't want to specify all of the columns in the query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that this should work for you. Keep in mind that CHECKSUM() isn't 100% perfect - it's theoretically possible to get a false positive here (I think), but otherwise you can just change the table name and this should work:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CHECKSUM(*) AS chksum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE()) AS row_num
    FROM
        My_Table
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE T1
INNER JOIN CTE T2 ON
    T2.chksum = T1.chksum AND
    T2.row_num <> T1.row_num
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` is needed so that you have some way of distinguishing rows. It requires an `ORDER BY` and that can't be a constant, so `GETDATE()` was my workaround for that.

Simply change the table name in the CTE and it should work without spelling out the columns.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I'm looking for, except that it's not returning anything when there's a duplicate row.  Have you actually tested this query?

Comment: Yes, I created a new table, added a pair of duplicate rows along with other non-duplicates as well as some with NULL values and it returned what I expected. I just retested it with a copy-paste from my answer and it worked again as expected.

Comment: The problem was on my end.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: +1 very nice and very performant. Although it is definitely possible for CHECKSUM to return the same value since its a Hash. e.g. `SELECT CHECKSUM('A')` and `SELECT CHECKSUM(142)` are the same. But it becomes less likely with the use `SELECT CHECKSUM(*)` but it still can happen. In case this very useful if you want to use it the same way a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) is used

Comment: Performant? Simply doing row_number() over (partition by checksum order by (select null)) in a derived table would be about a million times more performant.

Comment: Same thing for Mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm still confused about what "detecting them might be" but I'll give it a shot.

Excluding them is easy

e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM USERS
```

However if you wanted to only include them and a duplicate is all the fields than you have to do

```
SELECT 
   [Each and every field]
FROM
   USERS
GROUP BY
   [Each and every field]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

You can't get away with just using (*) because you can't  `GROUP BY *`
so this requirement from your comments is difficult

> a schema-independent means I don't want to specify all of the columns
>   in the query

Unless that is you want to use dynamic SQL and read the columns from `sys.columns` or `information_schema.columns`

For example

```
DECLARE @colunns nvarchar(max)
SET  @colunns = ''

SELECT @colunns = @colunns  + '[' +  COLUMN_NAME  +'], ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns  
WHERE table_name = 'USERS'

SET  @colunns  = left(@colunns,len(@colunns ) - 1)


DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT '  + @colunns 
          + 'FROM  USERS' + 'GROUP BY ' 
          + @colunns 
           + ' Having Count(*) > 1'


exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Please note you should read this [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#List) if you haven't already

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using CTEs in SQL Server.

Here is a sample on how to delete dupes but you should be able to adapt it easily to find dupes:

```
WITH CTE (COl1, Col2, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
    SELECT COl1,Col2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY COl1,Col2 ORDER BY Col1) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM DuplicateRcordTable
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
GO
```

Here is a link to an article where I got the SQL:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/23/sql-server-2005-2008-delete-duplicate-rows/

Answer (score 0):

I recently was looking into the same issue and noticed this question.
I managed to solve it using a stored procedure with some dynamic SQL. This way you only need to specify the table name. And it will get all the other relevant data from sys tables.

```
/*
This SP returns all duplicate rows (1 line for each duplicate) for any given table.

to use the SP:
exec [database].[dbo].[sp_duplicates] 
    @table = '[database].[schema].[table]'  

*/
create proc dbo.sp_duplicates @table nvarchar(50) as

declare @query nvarchar(max)
declare @groupby nvarchar(max)

set @groupby =  stuff((select ',' + [name]
                FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
                FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

set @query = 'select *, count(*)
                from '+@table+'
                group by '+@groupby+'
                having count(*) > 1'

exec (@query)
```